# how can i change the receiver of an action message of a textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my current project I have 1 textfield and 2 Buttons.

I want to change the title of the button that has been touched last with the text that i type in the textfield.

for example:
-> touch button 1 -> write e.g. "myButton1" in the textfield -> button1 title changes to "myButton1"
-> then touch button 2 -> write e.g. "anotherButton" in the same textfield -> button2 title changes to "anotherButton"

So the question is: How can I change the receiver of the action message of my textfield depending on the button that has been touched last?

Comment: you can have a "property lastTouched"which stores last button that you touched. ( i.e. when you touch a button, save the pointer of the button in "lastTouched".) At the "textFieldDidEndEditing" or other textFiled delegate method, you change the text of the button.

Comment: Thx. That was it. I just took an id property and stored the pointer of the button that had been touched. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the IBAction to catch touch event for 2 buttons:

```
    /// tap on button 1
    - (IBAction)onBtn1Tapped:(id)sender
    {
      _textfield.text = @"myButton1";
      UIButton * btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;
      [btn1 setTitle:@"myButton1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    /// tap on button 2
    - (IBAction)onBtn2Tapped:(id)sender
    {
       _textfield.text = @"anotherButton";
      UIButton * btn2 = (UIButton *)sender;
      [btn2 setTitle:@"anotherButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```